# Show that $f(x) = \{x, x+1\}$ is injective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm looking to show that the function

$$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R}), \ \ \ f(x) = \{x,x+1\}$$

is injective, where $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that contain exactly 2 elements.

My attempt:

For this function to be injective we need that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) = f(y) \Longrightarrow x=y$. Assume that $f(x)=f(y) \iff \{x,x+1\} = \{y,y+1\}$. Two sets are equal iff they contain the same elements.

Now if $x=y$ we are done. However if $x=y+1$ then $y=x+1$ and therefore $y=y+2$ which is always false.

How would I argue properly for the second case where $x=y+1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your explanation is correct. Maybe a better one would be the following.

If $x=y+1$ then $y=x-1<x<x+1$ hence $y \not \in \{x,x+1\}$ and $\{x,x+1\}\neq \{y,y+1\}$.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!